# Is there a way to ignore argument in delegate, for cleaner code in C#

Tags: c#

I have `Action<string, string>`, but in subscribed method I don't need that data. Can I subscribe method without those arguments somehow? I just don't want to make useless arguments. And I cant just make that action's data blank, since it's needed in other script

```
public Action<string, string> onKill;
```

Other script

```
health.OnKill += AddArmor; // Here I want to make AddArmor argumentless, but because of delegate, I can't
```

Comment: Yes, in C#, you can use the _ (underscore) symbol to ignore arguments in delegates.
OR in your case Lambda expression to ignore the arguments when subscribing the method to the delegate would be best fit

Comment: @IshworKhatiwada why not write it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual thing to do is to wrap it in a small lambda:

```
health.OnKill += (x, y) => AddArmor();
```

The old syntax for anonymous function offers to leave out `x` and `y` altogether:

```
health.OnKill += delegate { AddArmor(); };
```

Answer (score 1):

C#, you can use the _ (underscore) symbol to ignore arguments in delegates HERE in your case Yes, you can use a lambda expression to ignore the arguments when subscribing the method to the delegate.

```
health.OnKill += (_, __) => AddArmor();
```

Here, the lambda expression ignores both arguments from the Action<string, string> delegate by assigning them to _ and __ respectively.
The AddArmor method is then invoked without any arguments.

Comment: A single `_` is a "[discard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards)", `__` is a regular variable - you can also use `_` there even if the type is different

Comment: Using _discards_ is quite new to .Net. If you're running on an older version of the compiler the common workaround was to use `__` or even `___`. Once I've seen in code `class _`. This was used as placeholder in generic types. Looked really awkward, but worked.